# Failed with result 'signal'. при запросе к реплике бд Postgres

Tags: postgresql, репликация

```
мая 19 05:42:17 test_server java[1204157]: 05:42:17.850 [scheduling-1] [INFO] r.r.r.c.dao.AccPositionTransferDao - Start read 9493364 rows from AccPosition table DSF _DB
мая 19 05:42:21 s-msk-t-mfo-as5 systemd[1]: rb-custody-diasoft-replicator.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
мая 19 05:42:21 s-msk-t-mfo-as5 systemd[1]: rb-custody-diasoft-replicator.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

это лог с сервера.

подключение настраивается так:

```
datasource:
    dsf:
      pool-name: pool-dsf
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      minimumIdle: 0
      maximum-pool-size: 30
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
```

такие ошибки только на чтение таблиц с реплики с более чем 1 млн записей.
реплика на Postgres